# SwiftUI contextMenu only in dark mode

Tags: ios, swiftui, contextmenu, ipados, darkmode

Does anyone know why the contextMenu will only appear in dark mode when you put it in the view of a button:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
        
        }) {
            Text("Button with context menu")
                .contextMenu {
                    Text("Menu Item")
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Tried this on iOS and iPadOS, in the simulator and on device with os versions 14.4.1, 14.4.2 & 14.5.1.
I’m also almost sure, that this wasn’t always the case.

Comment: Looks like a good candidate for a Feedback to file with Apple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably a bug as [@jnpdx said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67387227/swiftui-contextmenu-only-in-dark-mode#comment119112293_67387227). However, if you put the `contextMenu` outside the Button, it works fine.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            print("Button pressed")
        }) {
            Text("Button with context menu")
        }
        /// outside
        .contextMenu {
            Button(action: {
                print("Menu button pressed")
            }) {
                Text("Menu Item")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

| Light mode | Dark mode |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Light mode - tap button, then press and hold and tap menu button] | [image: Dark mode - tap button, then press and hold and tap menu button] |

Comment: Unfortunately it does look really strange in my application when I place it outside, because I use e.g. rounded corners and when the context menu is showing, the whole button gets a gray rectangle as background.  But as a workaround it works for for now.

Answer (score 1):

### iOS 16

This Bug is fixed in iOS 16 Beta (20A5283p)